# Rest API Kafka stream

Tags: node.js, rest, api, apache-kafka

I am building a simple node.js rest API witch will produce data from Apache Kafka stream.
The API should produce JSON, witch I am having problem to achive.
Any help how to get JSON array of each message like `[{},{},{}]`? *(Or any better approach how to public Kafka stream and be able to consume Kafka stream for example by Power BI?)*

My current output looks like:

```
{"topic":"twitterFeeds","value":"RT @flyingtsunami: @SethAbramson **READ THIS UNTIL IT SINKS IN** #POTUS  #Comey's firing (he was); T…","offset":0,"partition":0,"highWaterOffset":1906,"key":null}
{"topic":"twitterFeeds","value":"RT @RCorbettMEP: Why does the @BBC news only …","offset":1,"partition":0,"highWaterOffset":1906,"key":null}
```

Output expected like:

```
[
{"topic":"twitterFeeds","value":"RT @flyingtsunami: @SethAbramson **READ THIS UNTIL IT SINKS IN** #POTUS  #Comey's firing (he was); T…","offset":0,"partition":0,"highWaterOffset":1906,"key":null}
,
{"topic":"twitterFeeds","value":"RT @RCorbettMEP: Why does the @BBC news only …","offset":1,"partition":0,"highWaterOffset":1906,"key":null}
]
```

My code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
    var output1 = '';
var http = require('http');  
var kafka = require('kafka-node'),
    Consumer = kafka.Consumer,
    client = new kafka.Client(),
    consumer = new Consumer(
        client,
        [
        { topic: 'twitterFeeds', partition: 0 }
        ],
        {
            autoCommit: false
        }
    );
    var output2 = consumer.on('message', function (message) {
     obj = JSON.stringify(message);
     output1 = output1 + obj;
    });

router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
        res.send(output1);
    });
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Hi @cricket_007, thanks for reply, I added expected output.

Comment: You want to write one array of multiple objects, when Kafka will only process one JSON object at time, individually? Why? And `output1` here is a string. Not a list, so where are you getting a list?

Comment: Regarding the ultimate question of the post - you can use Kafka Connect's JDBC Driver (or find a different connector for a database you would use, maybe Mongo, for example)  to push Kafka data to a database for any BI tool to consume. Point being - 1) You're only consuming from a single partition 2) What happens when this app resets? Do you lose all the data displayed on the web page? If you just wanted a REST API, then look at the Kafka REST proxy project

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently working on a similar project (if you'd be interested, help would be appreciated) - [scramjet-kafka](https://github.com/MichalCz/scramjet-kafka)

I have already solved the above problem in [scramjet DataStream.toJSONArray](https://scramjet.eu/docs/data-stream.html#scramjetcoretojsonarrayenclosure--stringstream) itself - it simply streams your data as a JSON Array. In your case it would be quite simply:

```
new ConsumerStream(
    client,
    [ { topic: 'twitterFeeds', partition: 0 } ],
    { autoCommit: false }
)
    .pipe(new scramjet.DataStream)
    // you may want to do some transforms here
    .toJSONArray()
    .pipe(process.stdout)
    // or pipe it to any other stream, accumulate and so on.
```

If you like the project and you could help - please get in touch via Github.

Comment: Hi, for sure! We could talk.

Comment: Cool. You can find me on github, in the scramjet repo you'll find an email to get in touch.